# Change the Fill Color of a path displayed in a DataGrid column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatemplate

I have a `DataGrid`, that shows a `Path` in the second column. This path is different based on the value in the bound property.

If I select the row, the `Stroke` color almost disapears in the background color of the selected row. The color of the text in the other columns changes from black to white in the selected row. But I cannot change the `Stroke`of the `Path`.

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="EpicsDataGrid"
    AlternationCount="1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    IsReadOnly="true"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Width="*"
            MinWidth="150"
            Binding="{Binding EpicName}"
            Header="Epic Name" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            Width="110"
            MinWidth="90"
            Header="Recurency">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Path x:Name="CalendarIcon"
                            Height="40"
                            Stretch="Uniform"
                            Stroke="Gray"
                            StrokeThickness=".5">
                            <Path.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Path">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger 
                                            Binding="{Binding RunName}" 
                                            Value="Yearly">
                                            <Setter 
                                                Property="Data" 
                                                Value="{DynamicResource calendar-recuring}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger 
                                            Binding="{Binding RunName}" 
                                            Value="Incidental">
                                            <Setter 
                                                Property="Data" 
                                                Value="{DynamicResource calendar}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Path.Style>
                        </Path>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Width="120"
            MinWidth="50"
            Binding="{Binding LastRun}"
            Header="Last year added" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I can set font attributes on row select but not `Path` attributes.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Wite" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another `DataTrigger` that sets the `Stroke` color to `White` if the corresponding row is selected. If the row is selected is given by the `IsSelected` property of the `DataGridRow` that you can bind using a `RelativeSource` with `AncestorType`. You could alternatively bind the `DataGridCell`, it makes not difference here.

Please also note that the original `Stroke` value assignment was moved into the style via a setter, because otherwise the local value would take precedence over the setter in the `DataTrigger`.

```
<Path x:Name="CalendarIcon"
    Height="40"
    Stretch="Uniform"
    StrokeThickness=".5">
    <Path.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Path">
            <Setter
                Property="Stroke"
                Value="Gray"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding RunName}" 
                    Value="Yearly">
                    <Setter 
                        Property="Data" 
                        Value="{DynamicResource calendar-recuring}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding RunName}" 
                    Value="Incidental">
                    <Setter 
                        Property="Data" 
                        Value="{DynamicResource calendar}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger 
                            Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"
                            Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Path.Style>
</Path>
```